# Using Mustache with joomla

Tags: php, rendering, mustache, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I am trying to use [Mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) with Joomla. What I would like it to do is check the whole page for the curly brackets and then change {{name}} for PERSONS NAME etc etc. I have tried playing around with it with the example they have on the website and have got the hello world to echo at the top of the page like the example, the thing is if I include the {{planet}} anywhere else on the page it just literally echo's {{planet}} , how can I get it to render the whole page and search for any instances of {{planet}} and replace it with world, so that I can include {{name}} in templates etc  ?.

This is the example I have put into my site templates index.php, im not sure how to direct it to render the whole page though, does anyone know if joomla stores the whole page in an array before its displayed or a way to do the above ?.

```
<?php
include('Mustache.php');
$m = new Mustache;
echo $m->render('Hello {{planet}}', array('planet' => 'World!'));
// "Hello World!"
?>
```

Comment: You can try to find the place where everything is collected into buffer ( `ob_start()` if it is done in Joomla ) and then get all buffer content into variable. Then pass it to mustach and echo the result. Something like that. Not familier with Joomla, so can't say for sure!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reverse how you're thinking about this. Instead of searching the page for instances of Mustache, you should pass the contents of the page to Mustache to render. It may be easier to store the contents in a separate template file.

```
<?php
include('Mustache.php');
$m = new Mustache;

$tmpl = "Content to display like Hello {{planet}}";

$view_data = array('planet' => 'World!');

echo $m->render($tmpl, $view_data);
```

How you manage storing and retrieving templates is up to you.